# Transform algorithm rules to mathematically equation

Tags: statistics

I created an algorithm in R, but I would like to have these "rules" as a mathematical equation for my thesis. Shortly what the algorithm does:

I want to create delivery time spans based on historical data.

In the dataset everything is grouped by postal codes. Every postal code has 96 rows, where every row is a 15 minutes time interval, which sums up to 24 hours. In these time intervals of 15 minutes packages are count that are delivered in the particular time interval.

The algorithm looks in every group at the row with the highest amount of count, where is will start. Then it will look at the row above and below this row and picks the row with the highest count of these two rows. Then from this group (of now 2 rows) it will again look at the row above and below the combined 2 rows and picks the highest one. This goes on and on untill 95% is reached of counts in a group.

More rules:

- When the algorithm sees two rows with both 0 then it will look at one row further. and chooses the highest count.
- When there are two rows with the same amount in them, it picks the row that has the highest amount of count of packages in all the rows (chunk) after the row its looking at. So if at the top chunk there is still 30% left in the group and in the bottom chunk there is 25%, it will go and take the row at the top into the time frame. However, when this row is taken, it just goes on with rule #1: looking at the next row above and below and detect which one has the most counts.
- If the count of packages in the top chunk and the bottom chunk are the same as well, it looks at in how much rows these counts are distributed and picks the chunk with the least rows. (This is because the time frame has to be as small as possible with the highest amount of count).

I dont know if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to capture this complex calculation as "a mathematical equation" for your thesis.

I think a good strategy for your readers would be to write your algorithm in semiformal pseudocode (easier to read than the sentences and paragraphs in the question). Work through a simple numerical example step by step.

(If you are writing in $\LaTeX$ there are [packages that will format pseudocode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms) nicely.)